# Titanium remote imageView doesn't update

Tags: imageview, titanium

I am making sort of a news app for a company, and i need my app to load an image, but the image in the url changes if you update the news, but if I update it, and I load the app again, the image still shows the previous image.

This is my code;

```
    imageremote = Ti.UI.createImageView({
         image: "http://www.mydomain.com/"+company+"/image0001.png"
    });

    win.add(imageremote);
    win.open();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding a unique param on the url so the url is not cached

```
imageremote = Ti.UI.createImageView({
     image: "http://www.mydomain.com/"+company+"/image0001.png" + "?t=" + new Date()
});

win.add(imageremote);
win.open();
```

Comment: After 2 days of searching on google, I came across this answer. Thanks @Aaron. Your answer saved my day. This needs +1.